# AccessDatabaseEngine (Free or Paid Version)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing, licence

I want to use Datasheet view in my SharePoint site but when i clicked on datasheet view, its not opened. i need to install **AccessDatabaseEngine**.

in my computer, i do not install Microsoft office and i do not have office license. so to install **AccessDatabaseEngine**, i needed license or its a free version ?

If we need to buy license for that then there is any free tool to use datasheet view

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Office license, just install **AccessDatabaseEngine** and you are good to go for Datasheet view